# Phaser: Tweening the numeric part of a BitmapText Object

Tags: tween, phaser-framework

I have a BitmapText object displaying a numeric score. i.e "Score: 50". Is there any way I can affect the score value with a tween when the score increases so that the number rolls up to to the new value, rather than just changing the text in one hit with:

```
this.scoreLabel.text = "Score: 100";
```

I know that I could achieve this with the update function with checks for a flag that I set when the score goes up to increase the score until the desired value is reached, however it seems a little unnecessary and wasteful to be checking for this flag every cycle of the update function.

Does anyone have any bright ideas how I could achieve this?

Ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone looking for a solution to this or a similar issue, this is how I achieved it:

```
DecoratorBonusScene.prototype.tweenScore = function(obj, startValue, endValue, time) {
        var scoreValue = {};
        scoreValue.score = startValue;
        var scoreTween = this.game.add.tween(scoreValue).to({score: endValue}, time);

        scoreTween.onUpdateCallback(function() {
          obj.text = "Score: "+scoreValue.score;
        });

        scoreTween.start();    
    }
```